# How do I merge 2 on_message functions in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to merge these 3 on_message functions into 1 function in discord.py rewrite version 1.6.0, what can I do?

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('in on_ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(hi):
    print("hello")

@client.event
async def on_message(Hey there):
    print("General Kenobi")

@client.event
async def on_message(Hello):
    print("Hi")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `on_message` function is defined as:

```py
async def on_message(message)
```

So you need to check the message contents in the `on_message` command and do whatever you need to depending on its contents, for that you can use the `Message` object's `content` attribute, as defined here [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        print("hello")
    elif message.content == "Hey there":
        print("General Kenobi")
    elif message.content == "Hello":
        print("Hi")
```

Do note though that if you want the bot to actually send a message, you need to replace `print(...)` with `await message.channel.send(...)`, as that is how you send a message, `print` only outputs to the terminal by default.